# r - rmarkdown - yaml - Is it possible to include inline, internal document hyperlink in title?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

is it possible to include an inline (internal document) hyperlink in the YAML title block of a RMarkdown document? Or is there a R package that allows this?

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
---
title: blah {#one1} and so on {#two2}
...
---


# Bibliography

1. Reference note to [explain](#one1) in title

2. Reference note to [explain](#two2) in title
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is parsed as markdown, so you can use regular markdown link syntax in order to get the behavior you want.

````
---
title: 'There is a link in this title...[LINK](#anchor)'
author: "Jason Punyon"
date: "6/16/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Bibliography

<p id='anchor'>Here's where I went!</p>
````

You could also just put the link in manually...

````
---
title: 'There is a link in this title...<a href="#anchor">LINK</a>'
author: "Jason Punyon"
date: "6/16/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Bibliography

<p id='anchor'>Here's where I went!</p>
````

Comment: Thank you so much for providing both solutions. I tested out the first solution and it worked perfectly.